# pulling record with several date in one column for sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum, case

I have a table with several columns but would like to pull a data from one particular column (sales no.).

sale no. column consist of group of numbers separated by a [-], i.e. `401001-402001-403001-404001`

When a sale is made, either `401001` or combination of all four is entered. What I'm trying to pull is a sale for just (`402001` and `404001`) combined; `401001` as single; `402001` as double. Please see below query. thank you in advance!!!!

```
select 
     sum(case 
             when (salesno like '402001' and salesno like '%404001%') then 1 else 0 
         end) as [combo]
from 
     table1
where 
    (salesno like '%402001%' and salesno like '%404001%')
    and (salesno not like '%401001%')
    and (salesno not like '%402001%')
    and (salesno not like '%403001%')
    and (salesno not like '%404001%')
    and saledate between '10/01/2013' and '10/31/2013'
group by
    (case when (salesno like '402001' or salesno like '%404001%')
```

Comment: I think we need a little more info.  specifically, what are your expected results?  are you just trying to get a count on the number of rows that have either 401001 or 402001 in the "sales no" column?

Comment: You should attempt to normalize your data. i.e. get rid of the encoded field and have a one-to-many table linking Sales Number to Groups. You can then write nice looking SQL to find all sales which have the 2 given groups.

Comment: If you know the string you're looking for is 402001-404001, why don't you specify it in your case?  `when (salesno like '%402001-404001%' then 1 else end`